# How can i customize the button if it set a AcceptButton of the form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, acceptbutton

I have implemented the custom button control with some additional options. And added my custom button into the form. When i set the Form.Acception is the added custom button, then I want to do some customization in the Button. I want to customize the button appearance in the Custom button class implementation, when it marked as AcceptButton of the Form.

Anyone suggest how can i know the button is marked as AcceptButton of the form in Button class?

Comment: see my updated answer, hope it will help you. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG:**

> protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>       {
>           base.OnLoad(e);
>           if (((Form)this.TopLevelControl).AcceptButton == this)
>               ....
>       }

**UPD:**

```
public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public override void NotifyDefault(bool value)
        {
            if (this.IsDefault != value)
            {
                this.IsDefault = value;
            }

            if (IsDefault)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Erm updated. is this any reference from button to form? this.TopLevelControl?

Comment: Thats is what the question is about

Answer (score -1):

You could traverse the parents to find the form via the parent property of its base class `Control`:

```
public partial class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form CheckParentForm(Control current)
    {
        // if the current is a form, return it.
        if (current is Form)
            return (Form)current;

        // if the parent of the current not is null, 
        if (current.Parent != null)
            // check his parent.
            return CheckParentForm(current.Parent);

        // there is no parent found and we didn't find a Form.
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        // find the parent form.
        var form = CheckParentForm(this);

        // if a form was found, 
        if (form != null)
            // check if this is set as accept button
            if (this == form.AcceptButton)
                // for example, change the background color (i used for testing)
                this.BackColor = Color.RosyBrown;
    }
}
```

Because of the recursion, it also works when the Button is placed on a Panel.

**Note: The accept button must be set before OnCreateControl is called** *(for example in the form's constructor)*

---

After some [googling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) I found a standard implementation:

You can also use: `this.FindForm();`

```
public partial class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        var form = FindForm();

        if (form != null)
            if (this == form.AcceptButton)
                this.BackColor = Color.RosyBrown;

    }
}
```

---

**Event shorter in C# 6.0:**

```
public partial class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        if (this == FindForm()?.AcceptButton)
            this.BackColor = Color.RosyBrown;
    }
}
```

**\o/**

Comment: button without form?)

Comment: You could create a button dynamically and add it later to a Form. It's parent can be _null_. Will never be an AcceptButton.

Comment: @garik Explain the -1?